# Alternative to transform: scale on a div?

Tags: html, css, transform, scale

I have this div:

```
<div class="mycontainer" 
     style="height: 50vh; width: 50vw; display: flex; align-items: center; 
     justify-content: center; overflow: visible" > 
    This is a very long text 
    this is a very long text 
    this is a very long text 
    this is a very long text
    this is a very long text
    this is a very long text
</div>
```

Now I would like to do an effect where the div shrink into a square with height: 35px and width: 35px. Obviously I can set the height and width of the div manually, but then the content inside the text would not shrink/scale along the div. I think about using `transform: scale` but as I am shrinking from 50vh and 50vw to 35px, I wouldn't know the exact scale number to use. This syntax doesn't work either: `transform: scale(calc(80vw / 35px), calc(80vw / 35px))`. What can I do?

Comment: *scale* is *scale* and has nothing to do with revealing content (size) - if that's what you're after...

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I am trying to use transform: scale as this scales the div along with its content as a whole. However since my original size is measured in vh and vw, I do not know exactly what scale number to use if I want to scale the div to an area measured by px.